# What is a term or expression for a very imaginative person?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

Someone who has a lot of ideas and different (efficient/productive) approaches in dealing with various situations. Someone who always comes up with some/another different, unexpected way for doing/approaching things/situations. Often with interesting and/or beneficial results. I am not looking for a "dreamer". Though, this imaginative person may often, easily, "switch" between realistic and fictional topics (and mix them together as well.)

Comment: "Innovative" comes to mind for me first.

Comment: The act is "out of the box thinking", the person..."creative, innovative, ingenious" ?

Comment: Isn't "out of the box thinking" the same as being open-minded/tolerant? But, open-mindedness doesn't have to imply someone is creative and has a lot of new (either realistic or fictional) ideas.

Comment: "Renaissance man" comes to mind - though it doesn't imply innovation as much as expertise and interest in an eclectic range of fields.

Comment: I like the historical touch to "Renaissance man" (sounds a bit like "Rain man" too :p)

Comment: @user76935 no, an "outside of the box" thinker completely implies creativity and innovation on his/her behalf. It's the best term thus far. +1 to Jo Bedard.

Comment: It doesn't really easily slip off the tongue, though, an "out of the box thinker"...

Comment: @user76935 How about "prolific thinker?" http://www.latimes.com/local/obituaries/la-me-2011notables-baran-photo.html

Comment: Just for my subjective, fussy preference, "prolific thinker" sounds a bit too formal. More for a nobel prize winner or high doctor/professor (someone who has a built-up social status/reputation) or something?

Comment: Also "lateral thinker" per Edward De Bono theory.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the person can think *outside the box*.  Or you could call them *[right-brained](http://lateralaction.com/articles/left-brain-or-right/)*.

And a more formal term that could not only describe the person but also describe their ideas and plans would be [ingenious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ingeniousness).

> having or showing an unusual aptitude for discovering, inventing, or contriving
>
> an ingenious detective :  marked by originality,
>   resourcefulness, and cleverness in conception or execution

Comment: Isn't right-brained only someone who uses the "right" side of his brain?

Comment: What about when he uses a lot of imagination around the knowledge and facts of his "left" side of the brain? It's not that he only thinks creatively, without using the left side of his brain ;-)

Comment: @user76935 - being right-brained means that you are a creative risk-taker that may push the envelope more than your left-brained brethren.  People can be considered very smart/genius and be labeled left or right-brained.  The phrase is showing the strength or dominance.

Comment: So, it could be used for someone whose left -and right brain work efficiently and equally well? However, who may be noticed, mainly for his dominant and outstanding imagination?

Comment: @user76935 - Of course.  Einstein was praised for his right-brained thinking (although he is so rare he might be praised for both sides).  http://www.brillbaby.com/early-learning/right-brain-learning/seeing-like-einstein.php

Comment: First thing, that I thought about Einstein! (Wasn't sure if I had to mention him as an example in the question, though :s)

Answer (score 0):

How about *prolific*, as in [prolific mind](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1298&dat=19631216&id=OrkwAAAAIBAJ&sjid=sYsDAAAAIBAJ&pg=4221,6514694)?

> [prolific:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prolific): marked by abundant inventiveness or productivity

Alternately, consider *effervescent*, *relentless brainstormer*, *endless font of ideas*, and *be a [think tank](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+think-tank) all by oneself*.

> [effervescent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vivid): marked by high spirits; vivacious
>
> *Al is an [effervescent thinker](http://www.campaignlive.co.uk/news/189918/) who seems to have more ideas in a minute than most people have in a day*.
>
> *GMA is a [think tank](http://www.philstar.com/modern-living/85766/solo-sonny-belmonte) all by herself*.
>
> [brainstormer](https://www.wordnik.com/words/brainstormer): one who brainstorms
>
> [brainstorm](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brainstorm): an idea that someone thinks of suddenly
>
> *Sasser, who writes about her successes and challenges in the college writing classroom, is an [endless font of ideas](http://www.elizabethfcornell.net/2012/08/29/here-now/)*.

Comment: Is the whole expression "be a think tank all by oneself"? It's not correct to, just, use "think tank"?

Comment: Just for my subjective, fussy preference, "prolific thinker" sounds a bit too formal. More for a nobel prize winner or high doctor/professor (someone who has a built-up social status/reputation) or something?

Answer (score 0):

A  *[resourceful](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Resourceful) person* is a definition used to indicate someone who is ingenious, capable and full of initiatives.